# Finding Direct Communication Channel to an IP Printer

Tags: .net, printing, wmi, snmp

I have an application that allows a user to pick a printer before printing. I need to be able to, using information returned from the .Net printer selection dialog, find a way to communicate over SNMP directly with the printer. One of the requirements for my application is that it not send any print jobs to the printer while the printer is paused or jammed or offline or out of paper, etc. I can get this information only via SNMP for the type of printer I have.

I have been using a WMI query to get the printer information, then deriving a communication channel to that printer using the ShareName and ServerName values in that WMI query. This has worked for well over a year.

Recently the network team here moved my application from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2008 R2 server. With the application in its new 2008 home, the values for ServerName and ShareName in the WMI query always come back empty making it impossible to communicate directly with the printer using my existing code.

Does anyone else have another way of communicating with printers directly only based on the user selecting a printer from the .Net printer select dialog? For the purposes of this application we are safe to expect the printer to always be of the same type and always be connected to the network.

Here is the WMI query I have been using:

```
"SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%MyPrinter'"
```

Appreciate it.

Comment: Are you not able to use WMI to directly get either the PrinterState or PrinterStatus?

Comment: Windows itself isn't reliably telling me if the printer is available, I did find a WMI query that would do that but it will often tell me the printer is unavailable when it is turned on and ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer I gave to [c# : How to Monitor Print job Using winspool_drv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645120/c-how-to-monitor-print-job-using-winspool-drv/3645165#3645165)

Here is an example of the using [Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(VS.85).aspx).

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.ShowDialog();
PrintDoc.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings;
PrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDoc_PrintPage);
PrintDoc.Print();

object status = Convert.ToUInt32(9999);
while ((uint)status != 0) // 0 being idle
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Printer where Name='" + pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "'");
    foreach (ManagementObject service in mos.Get())
    {
    status = service.Properties["PrinterState"].Value;
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

The documentation says that **PrinterState** is obsolete, and you should use **PrinterStatus**, that is unfortunate, considering **PrinterState** gives you all the statuses you are looking for.

That being said, both **PrinterState** and **PrinterStatus** *should* return > 0 if the printer is not available.