# How to capture Devexpress XtraReport printed date

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, devexpress, xtrareport

I've been using Devexpress XtraReport to display list of clients for print. Due to my system requirement, I'm expected to store the last print date in the database. I've tried the PrintProgress method but it couldn't take me any further. Besides, I've to make sure that the document is successfully printed before storing the date/time stamp in the database. Which method should I be using? Your ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could use winspool.drv, or as the answer to this [SO question on printer monitoring gives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645120/c-sharp-how-to-monitor-print-job-using-winspool-drv). CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save your data right after `report.Print()` is called? 
You cannot be 100% sure, if the report was successfully printed, since there are a million things out of your control which can go wrong (paper stuck, printer unplugged...). You just have to asume, that the report was printed. And if anything went wrong, the user will print it again, anyway.